# multiparty keeps saying that 'files' is undefined

Tags: node.js, rest, multipartform-data, postman

I just found this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty

And tried to test this function in my nodejs project with postman:

```
app.post('/upload/image', function(req, res) {
 var form = new multiparty.Form();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('received upload:\n\n');
  res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
 });
});
```

I've tried with the following postman POST request:

```
Headers: Content-type:image/jpeg 
Type: form-data - and then I choose a jpeg file
```

But I just keep getting this response:

```
received upload:{ fields: undefined, files: undefined }
```

Is this the correct approach when I want to send a image file to my REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that postman sends an array with the file, and it's inside an object with the name of the key you give the file, so if you use postman, you need to say: files."thekeyyougivethefileinpostman"[0]

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong `Content-Type`. `multiparty` only supports `multipart/form-data`-formatted requests. Change the `Content-Type` back to `multipart/form-data` from `image/jpeg` and it should work.

Comment: I just tried with Content-Type: multipart/form-data, but it keep returning files: undefined ?